# Virtual function implemented as template in derived class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

Having following code:

```
struct Base
{
    virtual void print(int x) = 0;
    virtual void print(float x) = 0;
};

struct Derived : public Base
{
    template<typename T>
    void print(T x)
    {
        std::cout<<x<<std::endl;
    }
};
```

Is it possible to do some C++ black magic(explicit instantiation for those types, some smart `using`, etc) to recognize the implementation of:

```
virtual void print(int x) = 0;
virtual void print(float x) = 0;
```

in `Derived` class in the form of:

```
template<typename T>
void print(T x)
```

Comment: You should not mix static (template) and dynamic (virtual) polymorphism. You might consider CRTP (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern), here

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there isn't.

What you can do is forward to a local template implementation:

```
struct Derived : public Base
{
    void print(int x) override { printTempl(x); }
    void print(float x) override { printTempl(x); }

    template <typename T>
    void printTempl(T x)
    {
        std::cout << x << std::endl;
    }
};
```

If you find that too verbose, and you have many such `print`s, you can also macro it:

```
#define PRINT_FWD(typ) void print(typ x) override { printTempl(x); }
```

Comment: At this moment I have the macro in the base class with all pure virtual functions and I use it like this in all derived classes, but I find this arcane...